# unable to run code in QTCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I just started a QT course and am having some problem running code in QTCreator.  When I try to run any code(even QT examples from my textbook)  I don't get any output.  it just says starting C:\ at the bottom.  Adny idea what I could be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very late answer but it turned out it was Avast antivirus that prevented me from running anything...